# Sorting a string with ord function

Tags: python, ord

I'm trying to split a string up using the ord function. This is my code

```
def sortString(info):
    res = isinstance(info, str)
    if res:
        for char in info:
            charValue = ord(char)

            #Lowercase
            if charValue > 96 and charValue < 123:
                lChar += char

            #Uppercase   
            elif charValue > 64 and charValue < 91:
                cChar += char

            #Punctuation
            elif charValue > 32 and charValue < 65:
                pChar += char

            #Spaces
            elif charValue == 32:
                numSpace += 1

        result = "cChar\nlChar\npChar\nnumSpace"

        return result
    else:
        return "Not a string!"
```

I want it to split the string based on upper case, lower case, punctuation and number of spaces. So "Hello, World!!" would output:

```
HW  
elloorld   
,!!  
1
```

The error I'm getting now is UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cChar' referenced before assignment. I tried to make an empty string but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Making `cChar` an empty string should have fixed the problem. What did you try exactly?

Answer (score 3):

You are updating `cChar` before initialising it and also `lChar` and `pChar`

```
def sortString(info):
    res = isinstance(info, str)
    if res:
        # INITIALISING
        cChar = lChar = pChar = "" #initialisation error fixed
        numSpace = 0 #initialisation error fixed
        for char in info:
            charValue = ord(char)

            #Lowercase
            if charValue > 96 and charValue < 123:
                lChar += char #initialisation error

            #Uppercase   
            elif charValue > 64 and charValue < 91:
                cChar += char #initialisation error

            #Punctuation
            elif charValue > 32 and charValue < 65:
                pChar += char #initialisation error

            #Spaces
            elif charValue == 32:
                numSpace += 1 #initialisation error

        result = cChar+ '\n' + lChar + '\n' +pChar + '\n' +str(numSpace) # indentation error and value error
        # you can also use this 
        # result = f"{cChar}\n{lChar}\n{pChar}\n{numSpace}" 
        return result #indentation error
    else:
        return "Not a string!"

print(sortString("HelloWhatsup"))
```

Please update your code it has errors

Comment: same for all other variables in the if statements in the loop. you could also fix the result variable at the end..

Comment: yes, when I ran it I found more errors, thanks for the insight, I have updated it, hopefully this helps

Comment: result = f"{cChar}\n{lChar}\n{pChar}\n{numSpace}" this just seems cleaner to me

Comment: absolutely, I wanted to show the changes made in the original code. Have added your insights as well! :)

Answer (score 1):

Making `cChar` an empty string fixes the problem. However, `lChar`, `pChar`, and `numSpace` also need to be defined.

Then there are two other problems: the `result =` and `return` lines are indented too far, and your `result` doesn't use the variables.

So to fix it:

```
cChar = lChar = pChar = ''
numSpace = 0
for char in info:
    # ...
result = '\n'.join([cChar, lChar, pChar, str(numSpace)])
return result
```

---

By the way, there are a lot of things you could improve. To start:

Use [guard clauses instead of nested conditionals](https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html), and use exceptions to signal errors

```
if not isinstance(info, str):
    raise TypeError("Not a string!")
```

Use Python's interval test syntax

```
if 96 < charValue < 123:  # Lowercase
    lChar += char
```

Answer (score 0):

**Because regular expressions are slow (?)**

If the rationale behind using `ord()` and range testing is to try and avoid the slowness of regular expressions, then you're going to be disappointed.

Let's compare a regular expression solution against `sortString()`, the approach using `ord()` and range testing, to group characters.

**Regular expression approach**

Regular expressions are used to match several groups of character ranges, and `zip()` to aggregate the matches into group lists.

```
>>> import re
>>> expr = re.compile(r"""([A-Z]+)  |         # Capitals.
...                       ([a-z]+)  |         # Lowercase.
...                       (\s+)     |         # Whitespace.
...                       ([!-/:-@\[-`{-~]+)  # Punctuation and symbols.
...                       """, 
...                       re.VERBOSE)
...
>>> [''.join(m) for m in zip(*expr.findall("The quick, and brown, fox"
...                                        " jumped (not leaped) over"
...                                        " the LAZY!!! dog =(."))]
['TLAZY', 
 'hequickandbrownfoxjumpednotleapedoverthedog', 
 '            ', 
 ',,()!!!=(.']
```

Timing it against the working implementation for `sortString()` in other answers, I get almost exactly the same time to complete 10**6 iterations.

```
>>> timeit.timeit("group_chars_regex(s)", globals=globals(), number=10**6)
16.637040594941936
```

*Running on a Linux VM on a Mac host that's over 10 years old.*

**Dictionary approach**

Dictionary lookups are fast, let's time a dictionary based solution that performs the groupings.

```
>>> groups = ("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
...           "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
...           " \t\r\n",
...           "!@#$%^&*()_+=-`~,..;:/?'\"[]{}\|")
>>> group_dict = {ch: n for n in range(4) for ch in groups[n]}
>>> 
>>> def group_chars(s):
...     lis = ['', '', '', '']
...     for ch in s:
...         lis[group_dict[ch]] += ch
...     return lis
```

`group_dict` maps each character to the index of the group it belong to. This index is used to update the strings in a list.

Timing it against `sortString()` we can see about 4s shaved off the time.

```
>>> timeit.timeit("group_chars(s)", globals=globals(), number=10**6)
12.557713539921679
>>>
>>> # The ord() and range testing method:
>>> timeit.timeit("sortString(s)", globals=globals(), number=10**6)
16.32978364895098
>>>
```

The `dict` approach is the fastest of the three methods of grouping.